# put similar values inside an array in php Json

Tags: php, mysql, json, encode

I have php code which gets data from the database. 
Now it needs to be converted in to Json Object. but I want to get the output like this

```
{
    "message": "true",
    "data": [
        {
            "c_id": "1",
            "c_titleId": "1",
            "cd_order": "1",
            "cd_img": "/imgs/cp1/cp01.png"
        },
        {
            "c_id": "2",
            "c_titleId": "2",
            "cd_order": "2",
            "cd_img": [
                "/imgs/cp3/cp301.PNG", "/imgs/cp3/cp303.PNG"]
        }

    ]
}
```

I have following code

```
function getalldata() {
    $sql = "SELECT chapters.c_id, chapters.c_titleId, chapterdetails.cd_order,
        chapterdetails.cd_img ,  chapterdetails.cd_desc
       from chapters
        INNER JOIN chapterdetails ON
        chapters.c_id = chapterdetails.c_id";
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    return $result;        
}


All the connections related code is seperated. this is the code which will be accessed from the app.

$result = $getdata->getalldata();
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num != 0) {
        http_response_code(200);
        $outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "true","data" => $outp));
        // echo json_encode();

    } else {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode(
                array("message" => "false",
                    "desc" => "No details available")
        );
    }
```

So what I want to do is, if multiple img urls are entered, then that should be send as an array for the relevant chapeter.

Comment: what do you get now as a JSON result with the snippet of code?

Comment: can you add an example on what nside the **$result**

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, I have very little knowledge with php while var_dump of   var_dump($result); is like this

object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(5)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(3)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}

SQL will return the  something like this

c_id, c_title, cd_desc, cd_img,  values related to those headers will be loaded

Comment: i mean the result fetched

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI

I am fetching data from the DB using sql query  ("Select * from chapterDetails");
I get all in the table.
id | cd_desc | cd_img | cd_order | c_id
1 |  test 1     | path1   | 1              | 1
2|    test 2    | path 2  | 2              |  1

with this data I want to generate a Json object as follows 

data  [
 cd_id : 1
cd_desc : [
      {1: test1}
      {2 test 2}
]
cd _img : [
   { path 1}
   {patj 2}
]

]

My requirement is to get array inside a json object so that It wont duplicate the chpater ID , chapter Title so that it is easy to process

Comment: but for the cd_img , how you manage it because your have an array of cd_img in the json ? do you have always 2 items in cd_img ? 
do you have two column for cd_img ?

Comment: I changed a little bit of the DB, now I have all under cd_desc, where I am planning to do is, identify an image with /imgs/ tab.

Comment: {
    "message": "true",
    "Chapters": {
        "0": [
            {
                "c_titleId": "1",
                "cd_desc": "Hello end."
            },
            {
                "c_titleId": "1",
                "cd_desc": "/imgs/01.png"
            }
        ],
        "1": [
            {
                "c_titleId": "2",
                "cd_desc": "text2"
            }
        ],
        "2": [
            {
                "c_titleId": "3",
                "cd_desc": "/imgs/02.png"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI
So I was managed to get some what i want, but it is not what really I want. What I want to generate is someting like this. in my solution there is an overhead that I have another array inside 

chapters [
 chapter 01 {
 cd_desc [
 "text 01", "/imgs/01.png" ,"text 01 cont"; 
 ]

 }
 chapter 02 {
 cd_desc [
 "text 02", "/imgs/02.png" ,"text 02 cont"; 
 ]

 }

]

Comment: sorry, you make me confused . can you edit your question and put there your table schema because it's not going clear like that

Answer (score 0):

To get you a little bit  close to the solution, the first thing you have to do is it creates some alias in your query, so this may help you to build you JSON data like :

> PS: in this example, the multiple-image per row is not handled

```
SELECT chapters.c_id as c_id ,
chapters.c_titleId as c_titleId, 
chapterdetails.cd_order as cd_order,
chapterdetails.cd_img as cd_img,
from chapters
INNER JOIN chapterdetails ON
chapters.c_id = chapterdetails.c_id
```

This query is going to return an array of rows like  :

```
//$data
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["c_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["c_titleId"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["cd_order"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["cd_img"]=>
    string(18) "/imgs/cp1/cp01.png"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["c_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["c_titleId"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["cd_order"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["cd_img"]=>
      string(19) "/imgs/cp3/cp301.PNG"
    }
  }
}
```

Then ,

```
$result = ["message" => true];
$result["data"] = $data;
$result_json = json_encode($result);
var_dump($result_json);


{
   "message":true,
   "data":[
      {
         "c_id":"1",
         "c_titleId":"1",
         "cd_order":"1",
         "cd_img":"\/imgs\/cp1\/cp01.png"
      },
      {
         "c_id":"2",
         "c_titleId":"2",
         "cd_order":"2",
         "cd_img":"\/imgs\/cp3\/cp301.PNG"
      }
   ]
}
```

If you want to manage multiple images per row, please update and explain more how your data is stored.

Comment: Thank you for support. 
I have two tables. called chapter and chapterdetails. 

Chapter has c_id, c_title
ChapterDetails has cd_id,cd_order,cd_desc , c_id (foreign key)

So now what I am trying is to save all the text and images row by row in the chapterDEtails table than using one for text and another for img path.
with this approach it would be easy for me to handle  the json data in the frontend. not sure when loading them what would be the consequences as this is my first time trying this